# Jquery .css and dynamically generated images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm generating some thumbnails using a url with querystring parameters, eg:

```
http://localhost:7229/GenerateImage.ashx?image=/media/map-v2.png&width=320&height=200
```

and I'm trying to assign this image to the background of an element using jquery:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDiv').css("background-image", "http://localhost:7229/GenerateImage.ashx?image=/media/map-v2.png&width=320&height=200");
  });
</script>
```

However the image isn't displaying. When I enter the url into my browser window, it does return an image as expected.. but for some reason I can't assign it as a background image using jquery.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong here? Is there a problem using dynamically generated images with css?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, you weren't using the correct background-image syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDiv').css("background-image", "url(http://localhost:7229/GenerateImage.ashx?image=/media/map-v2.png&width=320&height=200)");
  });
</script>
```

May I also suggest two other modifications:

1. Your image param in your URL should be URL encoded
2. It's neater to use `$(function(){})` instead of `$(document).ready(function(){})`

So the following would be the rewrite:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#myDiv').css("background-image", "url(http://localhost:7229/GenerateImage.ashx?image=%2Fmedia%2Fmap-v2.png&width=320&height=200)");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following code it should work:

```
$('#myDiv').css("background-image", "url(http://localhost:7229/GenerateImage.ashx?image=/media/map-v2.png&width=320&height=200)");
```

You forgot to apply the url() for adding the background image.